# Docker "Node.js version undefined detected"

Tags: node.js, docker, version, undefined

Until today, my angular project was running on Docker using Gitlab. But since this afternoon, I get an error I can't manage to solve.

Here's my DockerFile :

```
ARG REPOSITORY

ARG PORT

FROM ${REPOSITORY}/javascript:cert as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ /app

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

RUN npm i -g @angular/cli

RUN ng build --output-path=dist

FROM ${REPOSITORY}/nginx:cert

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT  ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

As I said, everything was working fine, but now when I reach "`Step 8/12 : RUN ng build --output-path=dist`", I get this error :

> "Node.js version undefined detected. The Angular CLI requires a
>   minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0."

It seems like it can't find my Node version, I don't understand why. I tried to set a specific npm version, but it changed nothing.

Any idea ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Does the base image have node installed?

Comment: I think yes, because if it wasn't the case it wouldn't have worked until now. I'm quite new to Docker, and i'm not sure to understand what the "base image" is. How can I check if it is well installed ?

Comment: Either somebody changed the base image or the new angular version conflicts with the version of Node that you have. You can check the first hypothesis by inspecting the image. For the second one, it is always a good idea to specify a specific version for your dependencies and manually upgrade when you are sure that the new version works.

Comment: When I type "docker images" in my console, I can find a "node" line with the "latest" tag. When I inspected it, I found nothing wrong, but i'm not sure what I should be looking for. 

Should I remove and recreate a new node image ?

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading/upgrading your Node.js version to 10.15 and it will work.
For some reason it wasn't working for 10.9

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: I faced similar issue, downgrading to 10.15 fixed it for me.

Comment: That's normally quite good evidence :) if you add this to your answer it is immediatly evident to the reader, that it's not just a wild guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same error as yours, but when i changed the folder, it worked for me. I am not sure what is happening. [image]

```
D:\OneDrive - XXX\Achyuth\Learning>node -v
v11.3.0

D:\OneDrive - XXX\Achyuth\Learning>npm -v
6.4.1
```